# Optimization with quadratic constraints and log function on R

Tags: r, optimization, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to solve this optimization problem in R:

[Optimization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtXsk.png)

To be clear the ω vector is the variable to optimize. σ and the Σ matrix are constants

I don't know how to modify the problem in order to use one R solver, all my attempts were failure...

This is coming from this quantitative finance article:

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2673124

Thank you for your help,

Arthur

This is what I tried using R and the nloptr package

```
  #Compute the covariance matrix with asset returns
  Cov<-cov(Asset)

  #fonction to optimize
  D <- function(P) {
    -sum(log(abs(P)))
  }

  #gradient of the objective function
  D_g <- function(P) {
    -1/P
    }

  #inequality function with the Jacobian
  ineq <- function(P) {
    cont<-rep(0,length(P))
    for(i in 1: length(P)){
      cont[i]<-sum(P[-i]*Cov[i,-i])
    }
    return(list(
      "constraints" = sqrt(t(P) %*% Cov %*% P) - target,
      "jacobian" = (P * diag(Cov)+cont) / sqrt(t(P) %*% Cov %*% P)
    ))

  }

  # Optimisation under constraints
  # Poids is the initial weight: 1/vol
  # D is the function to optimize
  # D_g is the gradient of this function
  # ineq is a function with constraint and jacobian of it
  Poids=Pos*1/sqrt(diag(Cov))/sum(1/sqrt(diag(Cov)))

  par0 <-
    nloptr(
      Poids,
      D,
      eval_grad_f = D_g,
      lb = NULL,
      ub = NULL,
      eval_g_ineq = ineq,
      opts = list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_LBFGS",
                  "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-8)
    )
```

Comment: Please add the homework tag, if this is a homework question. Furthermore, please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: QCQP won't work.

Comment: @sasha why it wont work?

Comment: How do you express the log-function within QCQP? You would need the exponential-cone and some reformulation (not QCQP anymore). (and yes: that question is broad, the task incomplete and it looks like you invested just 2 mins to express it while every answer will take much more time)

Comment: @BasJansen it's for work and personal use

Comment: @sascha i'm gonna add what I tried in my original question

Comment: This question is still of very low quality. Look at it and think about saying things like *all my attempts were failure...* while not giving any additional info (error, no convergence, pc blown up...). Furthermore: first you talked about QCQP (which is a well-defined problem!), now you presented a general nonlinear-programming approach which is something very different! Without using R or this lib i will also tell you that i'm 99.9% sure, ```NLOPT_LD_LBFGS``` is not able to use constraints (it's a classic unconstrained solver supporting bounds only) which would be obviously a problem here!

Comment: No need to be rude. If i'm asking it's because my knowledge in optimization is very limited. I understand that my question is certainly very large but i'm trying to do it right

Comment: I'm just pointing out, that this, as presented, will not attract much helpful people here as it's hard to work with (see my points + external paper without own summary and details; no reproducible example, still no error-description).

Comment: I understand what you say but all I need to know is what type of algorithm can resolve this type of problem and how to solve it in R... Errors descriptions are pointless because I don"t even know which algorithm i need to use whith nlopr

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which worked. After some research, I'v found that the COBYLA algorithm of the nlopr package can solve this type of problem. Sorry for my misunderstanding on advanced optimization and the way to do it in R.

Here is the code if someone from the finance industry need to do it quickly:

```
  #Asset is simply returns from financial asset 
  target=0.1/sqrt(252)
  #Compute the covariance matrix
  Cov<-cov(Asset)

  #fonction to optimize
  D <- function(P) {
    -sum(log(abs(P)))
  }

  #gradient of the objective function
  D_g <- function(P) {
    -1/P
    }

  #inequality function with the Jacobian
  ineq <- function(P) {
    return(sqrt(t(P) %*% Cov %*% P) - target
    )
  }

  LoB=rep(0,length(Pos))
  UpB=rep(0,length(Pos))
  for(i in 1:length(Pos)){
    if(Pos[i]>0){
      LoB[i]<-0.00001
      UpB[i]<-10
    }else{
      LoB[i]<- -10
      UpB[i]<- -0.00001
    }
  }

  # Optimisation under constraints
  # Poids is the initial weight: 1/vol
  # D is the function to optimize
  # ineq is a function with constraints

  Poids=Pos*1/sqrt(diag(Cov))/sum(1/sqrt(diag(Cov)))

  par0 <-
    nloptr(
      Poids,
      D,
      eval_grad_f = NULL,#D_g,
      lb = LoB,
      ub = UpB,
      eval_g_ineq = ineq,
      opts = list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_LN_COBYLA",
                  "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-12,
                  "maxeval"=10000,
                  "xtol_abs"=1.0e-12)
    )
```

I perfectly understand that for some people the question was to large and the theorical problem has not been resolved. Once again, I'm don't have enough knowledge on advanced optimization...